# Save a Rendered Razor View as HTML string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

Is it possible, once a `Razor View` has been rendered in the browser, that the HTML and the contents of the mark up (images, tables, data etc.) can be saved as a string or other type?

I want to be able to generate the `Razor View` for the customer to check everything is ok in the output, then I want them to click a button that saves all of the HTML (Without all of the razor markup etc.).

How do you pass the HTML back to an `Action`, if it has to be processed pre-rendering, then how can this also be done.

I can then use this to generate PDF's and also save time on processing, as I will save the string in a database.

BTW, this is not a partial view nor will it use partial views, also I know there are still some things to fix in the Razor View, I am more interested in the saving the HTML at this point.

TIA

[HTML Pre rendering](https://jsfiddle.net/pkg0u89x/) 
[HTML Post Rendering](https://jsfiddle.net/n3u2f4s5/)

Comment: What will the customer be checking?  Bear in mind that whilst the HTML may be correct, it may reference javascript, images or css that aren't rendered in the HTML.  Unless the customer is going to look at the HTML directly, just having this one part of the solution may not actually help.  I suspect you would do better by creating a UAT environment, and publishing your actual code there, for the customer to see the 'real' web site.

Comment: They have to check that the data that appears on the page is correct as part of their QA process. I am happy to render the page Server side (in memory) if this is even possible. I can also edit the string to remove <script> etc, so I am not too concerned about that.

Comment: QA should be using a QA/UAT environment, and be looking at the actual output, not some 'snapshot' that might have been tweaked prior to them seeing it.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding things. This has nothing to do with a UAT environment, it shows the customer a small set of their own data between two dates. The QA people are mechanical technicians, they have no need for UAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Middleware to obtain a copy of the HTML that is being sent to the browser. Create a class named `ResponseToString` with the following content:

```
public class ResponseToStringMidleware
{
    RequestDelegate _next;

    public ResponseToStringMidleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var isHtml = context.Response.ContentType?.ToLower().Contains("text/html");
        Stream responseBody = context.Response.Body;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            context.Response.Body = memoryStream;

            await _next(context);

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 200 && isHtml.GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                string html = new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEnd();
                // save the HTML

            }
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(responseBody);
        }
    }
}
```

Replace the `// save the HTML` with some code to persist the HTML as required. Register the Middleware in your Startup's `Configure` method early:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseMiddleware<ResponseToStringMidleware>();
    ...
}
```

Further infomration: [Middleware in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/middleware)